# How to check if number and has nine characters?

Tags: javascript, validation

how do I check if a text entered is a number and has nine characters in javascript?

Intengo do with the code below but shows me correctly.

```
    function numberValidate(idtelf){
    var number = document.getElementById('idtelf');

    var charactersLength = number.value.length;
    if(isNaN(number) || charactersLength !=9  )
    {
        alert(  "Enter a valid number ");
    }
    else {
            alert(  "correct");
       }
};
```

Comment: I would recommend using the Jquery validate library.

Comment: @Oisin No. jQuery isn't a magical solution for every problem.

Comment: How does this not work? What's wrong with it?

Comment: try isNaN() function

Comment: _number_ is html element, so `isNaN(number)` always `NaN`, change it to `isNaN(number.value)`

Comment: Use `regex` it's so better `/^[0-9]{9}$/.test(document.getElementById('idtelf').value)`

Answer (score 2):

This one checks also if it's a number. Other answers would accept "123456   " (3 spaces at the end) as well.

```
function numberValidate(idtelf){
    var input = document.getElementById('idtelf');

    var number = parseFloat(input.value);
    var charactersLength = input.value.length;
    var numberLength = (""+number).length;
    if(isNaN(number) || charactersLength !=9 || numberLength !=9 )
    {
        alert(  "Enter a valid number ");
    }
    else {
            alert(  "correct");
       }
};
```

If number can'n be float then instead of parseFloat() use parseInt()

Comment: it returns 123, but then I check ("" + 123).length and it returns 3, not 5, as all the other answers would (not to talk about wether 123ad is a number)

Comment: so, you code return _correct_ for `123456789asdasdasdasd`, seems this not good

Comment: Ok, you're right, that's also a possible interpretation. I'll improve it.

Comment: _Other answers would accept "abcdefghi" as well._ - here you wrong, because in this case _isNaN_ return true

Comment: i think better use _Number_ function that return _NaN_ if srting not a number, so you can check just string length, and number not is NaN

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**HTML**

```
<input id="idtelf">
```

**Javscript**

```
var number1 = document.getElementById('idtelf');

number1.onblur = function () {
    var charactersLength = number1.value.replace(/\s/gi,"").length;
    if(isNaN(number1.value) || charactersLength != 9)
    {
      alert("Enter a valid number ...");
    }
    else {
            alert("correct");
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rreyaovy/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this..This handles all type of input..

```
    function numberValidate(idtelf){
    var input = document.getElementById('idtelf');

    var number = input.value.toString();
    var myString = number.replace(/\D/g,'');
    if(number.length ==9 && number.length == myString.length)
    {
        alert(  "Correct");
    }
    else {
            alert(  "Enter a valid number");
       }
};
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/a24ymxe7/)

Comment: You're 8 minutes late :) I have the same answer with some explanation

Comment: Actually I think you still have one redundant toString()

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that uses a simple regular expression to test if the value is a 9-digit number.

```
function numberValidate(id){
  var number = document.getElementById(id).value,
    regex = /^[0-9]{9}$/;

  if (regex.test(number)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

We can use this function like this:

```js
function numberValidate(id){
  var number = document.getElementById(id).value,
    regex = /^[0-9]{9}$/;

  if (regex.test(number)) {
    return true;
    alert();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
      
var result1 = numberValidate('testNum1');
var result2 = numberValidate('testNum2');
var result3 = numberValidate('testNum3');
  
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Input 1: ' + result1 + '<br/>Input 2: ' +  result2 + '<br/>Input 3: ' +  result3;
```

```html
<input id="testNum1" value="1234">
<input id="testNum2" value="123456789">
<input id="testNum3" value="1234567891011">

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if(isNaN(number.value) || charactersLength !=9 )
```

instead of this

```
if(isNaN(number) || charactersLength !=9  )
```

Comment: I would suggest to `trim` and handle the case when number is float (how to deal with this `1234567.9` for example?).